# Faking web requests in Rails test without Fakeweb

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, httpclient, stub, handsoap

I'm using the Handsoap gem with Httpclient gem as the driver in a Rails app.

How can I prevent network calls from Handsaop/Httpclient gems in test cases?

FakeWeb doesn't support Httpclient.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How to prevent network calls from Handsaop/Httpclient gems in test cases?

Answer (score 3):

You can use WebMock http://github.com/bblimke/webmock. It has support for Httpclient.

Comment: And you can consider using [VCR](http://github.com/myronmarston/vcr) in conjunction with WebMock.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mock driver for Handsoap (`Handsoap::Http::Drivers::MockDriver`). See in the tests for an example.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, FakeWeb currently only supports libraries based on Net::HTTP.

[Here's a ticket about adding HttpClient support](http://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb/issues/#issue/6), which also references a couple older forks that attempt to do it.